# How to create a simple button for a script?

Tags: scripting

I'm struggling trying to create a simple button for this script:

```
for Nlys in (3,8,11,13,16,5):
    bpy.context.object.data.layers[Nlys] = True

for Nlys in (0,1,2,4,7,10,14,17,9,12,15,18,6,20,5,19,28):
    bpy.context.object.data.layers[Nlys] = False
```

In Maya I was used to drag an drop the code into a shelf and the button was created automatically. 
Is there a way to to this in Blender?

---

Update: [This](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18951/run-actions-with-a-custom-button) helped me to figure out a solution for this result.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ray Mairlot for pointing me in the right direction!